# Spring-Scheduling Problems: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I try to deploy the application, but the console show me this error, I'm not familiar with Spring MVC and Spring scheduler. This is my first project.

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils
at org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:113)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
... 24 more

Aug 28, 2014 10:10:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class       
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:      org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils
at      org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:113)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
... 24 more
```

Beans.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Initialization for data source -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_records" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<!-- Definition for studentJDBCTemplate bean -->
<bean id="studentJDBCTemplate" class="com.tutorialspoint.dao.impl.StudentJDBCTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<!-- BATCH MODULES -->
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="scheduleCsvParse" class="com.tutorialspoint.batch.ScheduleCsvParse" />
 </beans>
```

Since, this is a Spring-MVC. I entitled my project "Full-Spring" with a Full-Spring.xml as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.tutorialspoint" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Form Handling</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FullSpring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FullSpring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:Beans.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

ScheduleCsvParse.class is composed of this.

```
package com.tutorialspoint.batch;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

import com.tutorialspoint.dao.impl.StudentJDBCTemplate;

public class ScheduleCsvParse {

@Autowired
private StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate;

public StudentJDBCTemplate getStudentJDBCTemplate() {
    return studentJDBCTemplate;
}

@Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
public void parseCsvFile() {
    System.out.println("Entered parseCsvFile");

    String csvFile = "C:/Users/Paul.Aragones/Documents/Full-Spring3/FullSpring/sample/StudentRecords.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            studentJDBCTemplate.create(row[1], Integer.parseInt(row[0]));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Done");
    System.out.println("Exited parseCsvFile");
    }

}
```

This is my StudentJDBCTemplate.class

```
package com.tutorialspoint.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import com.tutorialspoint.bean.Student;
import com.tutorialspoint.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.tutorialspoint.mapper.StudentMapper;

public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDAO {
   private DataSource dataSource;
   private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
      this.dataSource = dataSource;
      this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }

   public void create(String name, Integer age) {
      String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";

      jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL, name, age);
      System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);

   }

   public Student getStudent(Integer id) {
      String SQL = "select * from Student where id = ?";
      Student student = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForObject(SQL, 
                        new Object[]{id}, new StudentMapper());
      return student;
   }

   public List<Student> listStudents() {
      String SQL = "select * from Student";
      List <Student> students = jdbcTemplateObject.query(SQL, 
                                new StudentMapper());
      return students;
   }

   public void delete(Integer id){
      String SQL = "delete from Student where id = ?";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id);
      System.out.println("Deleted Record with ID = " + id );
      return;
   }

   public void update(Integer id, String name, Integer age){
      String SQL = "update Student set name = ?, age = ? where id = ?";
      jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, name, age, id);
      System.out.println("Updated Record with ID = " + id );
      return;
   }

}
```

This program was running before I tried setting up the Spring-Scheduler. When I tried adding this component especially putting on the `<task:annotation-driven />` tag on Beans.xml, this is where the error happened. Do you know any idea how to properly fix this configuration in order to run the scheduler?

Thanks and appreciate your help!

Comment: it is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. check if all required spring jars are in classpath

Comment: More than that : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/support/AopUtils. Check your classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Ekansh, thanks for the help and reply. I added the `org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar` to my code but the error is still there. I don't know what the tag `<task:annotation-driven />` did to the code to show error. `SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAsyncAnnotationProcessor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
`

Comment: @PaulaKristin it seems that you also need aopalliance.jar. Take the one from this link http://sourceforge.net/projects/aopalliance/files/aopalliance/1.0/ , don't take aopalliance-alpha because it doesn't contain the class you need.